# Image upload in cell phone - Not even calling Java code

Tags: angular, typescript

I already wrote code to upload image last week which is working fine in Desktop. But it NOT working in cell phone. I have given debug points in java, When I click on submit the debugger is not coming to Java Controller itself.

Html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #studentForm="ngForm" class="form-horizontal" >
   <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!inspectionForm.form.valid">
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save
   </button>
</form>
```

component TS:

```
   selectFile(event) {
       this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
     }

    onSubmit() {
        . . .
        . . .
        . . .
        this.myService.create(this.model, this.fileupload.selectedFiles.item(0))
        this.location.back()
   }
```

Service TS:

```
 create2(student: Student, file: File)  {
           this.pushFileToServer(file, student).subscribe(event => {
             . . .
             . . .
             . . .
           })
     }

    pushFileToServer(file: File, student: Student) {
        const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
        const studentString = JSON.stringify(student.notifications);

        formdata.append('file', file);
        formdata.append('name', student.name);
             . . .
             . . .
             . . .
        return this.http.post("/api/student/create", formdata);
    }
```

Java Controller (Spring boot and SQL Server):

```
    @PostMapping("/api/student/create")
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam("name") String name) {

            . . .
            . . .
            . . .
            image.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
            try {
                image.setImageStream(file.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            image.setSize(Math.toIntExact(file.getSize()));
            imageService.create(image);

}
```

**NEW APPROACH - Error: TypeError: dataURI.split is not a function**

HTML:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
```

Component TS:
selectedFile: File;

```
onSubmit() {
    // some code - logic
    this.studentService.create(this.model, this.selectedFile);
```

}

```
onFileChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
}
```

Service TS:

```
create(student: Student, file: File)  {
       this.pushFileToServer(file, student).subscribe(event => {
       })
 }

pushFileToServer(file: File, student: Student) {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    const notificationString = JSON.stringify(student.notifications);
    let imgBlob = this.dataURItoBlob(file);

    formdata.append('file', file);

    return this.http.post("/api/student/create", formdata);
}

dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataURI.length; i++) {
      array.push(dataURI.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
      type: mimeString
    });
}
```

Comment: We need more info. What doesn't work about it? Are you seeing an error? Does it hit the backend Java controller?

Comment: I don't see any error in browser console. As I said it doesn't hit java itself.

Comment: Since I am new in Angular and never worked in Angular 1, I am trying to understand how this works. http://jsfiddle.net/sc1qnw4n/206/  I am not getting how that custom directive works. If I get it done in Angular 4, I THINK that will work in cell phone.

Comment: It listens for a `change` event on the file input. When change is heard, it will take the first selected file, and pass it into a `FileReader`. When it has been read, it sets `$scope.fileread` to the data

Comment: Ohh ok, then in that case it similar to my code: this.fileupload.selectedFiles.item(0)        right?

Comment: Is `selectedFiles` not an array? If so, you should be doing `this.fileupload.selectedFiles[0]` instead...

Comment: correct, in that case don't you think it is easy to write a onchange instead of a custom directive to make it easier ? I am still struggling to understand that jsfiddle example...

Comment: Yep, there is no need to do it in a directive other than to reuse it. You're fine doing it in an onchange event

Comment: Tried the new approach, but getting type script error. Need help seriously....

Comment: What error? Can you try creating a StackBlitz to reproduce the issue?

Comment: TypeError: dataURI.split is not a function... I really don't know how to create stackBlitz...   I have updated my question with new approach code

Comment: Think about what the error message is saying. `dataURI` is an object that does not have a `split` method. So that likely means it's not a string. Use a debugger and set a breakpoint there, or use `console.log(dataURI)` to see what it is.

Comment: Also, in that code, you're creating `imgBlob` and never using it. If you're sending the POST request as multipart form data, then there is no need to convert the `File` object anyway

Comment: correct, my should have been formdata.append('file', imgBlob);.   and you are correct dataURI is not a string. So how to pass the string of the file. I mean if you see my code, onchange I am getting the file by doing event.target.files[0] and passing that. what is right way of doing it please...

Comment: Just pass the file object (not the data uri) to form data

Comment: just passing the file object means what I did in my first try... isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is. Can you see the HTTP request in the browser's network tools?

Comment: @user184994 - I have explained and put all code and given so much details, still I got Downvote. Now I am not able to ask any question. Please Upvote or let me know how I can improve to get upvote...

Comment: I have explained and put all code and given so much details, still I got Downvote. Now I am not able to ask any question. Please Upvote or let me know how I can improve to get upvote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update you all... apologies for that.
The real error was in spring configuration. The default properties in spring is to upload 1MB. But the picture in my cell phone was about 5MB. So once I change the file upload size, it worked without any code change in Angular side.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Angular to send the HTTP request, you need to `.subscribe` to the `Observable`, like so:

```
onSubmit() {
    // some code - logic
    this.studentService.create(this.model, this.selectedFile).subscribe((res) => {
       // This will execute once the HTTP call has returned.
       console.log("Success");
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, bu no luck. Then I found the real problem was spring configuration.